USB Key Token with DevOps pipeline
We have a single PC used for digitally signing code in published apps. This computer has a USB dongle that contains the key for signing. When publishing the application, SmartCard PIN entry prompt comes up and the developer must enter the PIN code to finish the publish process.
Our Azure pipeline to publish application is unusable because of this, as it requires the developer to sign in to the PC and enter the PIN into the prompt.
What are our options here? Can this be used with the pipeline somehow? Is there an option that would leverage the USB hardware key without having to enter the PIN?
I was hoping the pipeline could be notified of the publish process being halted, so that I can programatically enter the PIN. However, the pipeline does not get notified of the prompt, it just keeps executing without any notification of anything halting the publish process.
Current pipeline:

variables:
  poolName: 'Build Machine'
  agentName: [redacted]
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

pool:
  name: 'Build Machine'

jobs:
- job: BuildAndPublish
  steps:
  - checkout: self
    displayName: 'Checkout Code'

  - task: UseDotNet@2
    inputs:
      packageType: 'sdk'
      version: '8.0.204'

  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: Install .NET MAUI
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        & dotnet nuget locals all --clear
        & dotnet workload install maui

  - script: |
      dotnet publish -c Release C:\Users\[redacted]\source\repos\[redacted]\[redacted]\[redacted].csproj -f net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0 /p:GenerateAppxPackageOnBuild=true /p:UapAppxPackageBuildMode=SideloadOnly /p:AppxBundle=Never --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/publish
    displayName: 'Publish Project'

  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    inputs:
      pathToPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/publish'
      artifactName: 'PublishedApp'
      publishLocation: 'Container'```


Can you share more details about the devops pipeline? How is your pipeline currently defined? Which step do you need to sign after?  And your signature method, running scripts or having specific APPs?

I warn against skipping the PIN entry, since this is assumed to be the final step of an app review. Without it, the resulting signature still looks like one, but no longer has a practical meaning.

@KevinLu-MSFT the pipeline is very simple, it installs workloads and run a publish script command. Normally, in Visual Studio, I can define the sign tool or the cert file location to execute the publish script. However, now with the USB token drive, this is no longer possible. I can only specify the that I wish to use sign tool and that automatically triggers the SmartCard window to pop up during the publish process. I have edited my question to include the pipeline.

@guidot I agree, I do not really wish to skip this step. However, I want continuously integrate our apps without developers having to wait for their turn on the build machine a having to wait for a window prompt to enter the PIN. It is for internal systems, so the use of the build machine is quite frequent a queueing occurs often.

@Coop Do you mean that if you use Visual Studio directly locally, you also can't complete the whole process directly after using USB token drive?  And  how do you use USB token drive for authentication locally now?

@KevinLu-MSFT Locally I can publish fine without the USB token drive. However, apps signed by older certificates we use to use cannot be installed anymore. Only apps signed by the USB token drive are recognized as safe to install. This cannot be done locally, I have to RDP to the build machine and execute the publish process there. Hence why all developers must use a single PC with a USB dongle in it to publish their apps.

@KevinLu-MSFT The USB dongle is in the PC and is registered as it is in "local store". So, when I specify the "use local store" signing, this automatically triggers the SmartCard PIN prompt window during the signing process

@Coop Currently, when you use the release pipeline to publish the app, it will popout the window to enter the PIN and then continue the deployment, right?

@KevinLu-MSFT The popout window comes up as the last thing during the publish script execution, so as soon as I enter the PIN manually, the pipeline continues, publishes the artifacts etc. If I don't enter the PIN it will just sit there, executing and nothing is happening

@Coop I can understand the process now. But I am afraid that there is no such method can meet your requirement. The release process is continuous, and it cannot automatically pause/stop the Pipeline based on whether a pin code is required. While waiting for the pin code to be entered, the release pipeline will continue to run. This is expected. And because the pin code requires a USB token drive and manual input, we cannot integrate it into the Pipeline. We still need to keep the current manual input.
